# What to use instead of FTP

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2, file-sharing

I get this question all the time from people who run Windows-based web servers. FTP, while ubiquitous, has numerous flaws shortcomings, not all of which can be solved simply by slapping SSL/TLS on top of the existing FTP protocol.

So is there a protocol, configuration, or other solution that a Windows user can employ for general-public file-transfer use to take the place of FTP? The typical requirements are simple and intuitive:

- It needs to be something that a relatively unskilled admin can set up and manage
- Access to this protocol needs to not implicitly grant access to other resources as well
- It needs to be safe over the Internet

---

Here are some *no-go* solutions which do not satisfy the question's requirements, but are typically suggested anyway. They're included here to urge you to avoid suggesting them as answers

- Cygwin and other SSH solutions, which besides being complicated for a novice to set up, also implicitly grant command-shell access to the visitor allowing him to do more than just upload and download files (i.e. execute arbitrary code)
- RDP, which while it has file-sharing capability, also grants the visitor desktop access, allowing him to do more than just upload and download files
- FTPS, FTPES, and other FTP-based solutions. Encryption isn't the only problem with FTP. Otherwise we wouldn't be asking this question.
- Windows File Sharing, which is not safe for use over the Internet, and is typically blocked by ISPs for that reason
- DAV, unless it can be VERY easily set up and secured (which is typically not the case)

---

<sup>*Note that this is very explictly and very intentionally **not** a [shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). We're not asking which popular product best satisfies a laundry-list of features. Instead, we're looking for potential solutions for a common problem.*</sup>

Comment: you're explicitly denying the two only reliable alternatives (SFTP and WebDAV) without giving any valid reason. It seems like you're being limited by your own incomplete knowledge of these protocols and the tools available for them and that is your main issue here.

Comment: @Stephane SFTP is perfectly reasonable if it can be done without granting shell access (which typically isn't the case). DAV is perfectly reasonable if it can be simple for a novice to set up and secure (which typically isn't the case).

Comment: Having access to the remote desktop doesn't strike me as really a problem so long as the apps are locked down properly. (Which, at least in Server 2012, is the default.)

Comment: You don't need to give shell access for SFTP. WebDAV is trivial to setup and use by a novice: give them the URL, tell them to type it in explorer, enter their credentials when prompted when asked for and you're done. Like I said: your limitation is your own knowledge: take an afternoon to play with these protocols and you'll find out that they fit your requirements (at least the ones you listed)

Comment: @Stephane By "set up" I'm referring to server-side set up, not client-side. I'm intimately familiar with the protocols, having myself written implementations for many of them including WebDAV and FTP. The core of the question isn't "what should **I** use on **my** server", it's "what should I encourage beginner admins to use on **their** servers." SFTP very critically relies on shell access; the only way around it is to create a modified restricted shell (e.g. rssh) which pretends to be a shell but only allows you to run SFTP-related commands. This is non-trivial to set up on Windows.

Comment: @MichaelHampton It violates the [principle of least privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) and dramatically increases your attack surface and risk of escalation. Allowing flash videos to be embedded in PDF documents is *theoretically* safe, but it's crazy-dangerous in the real world.

Comment: Well, if you want to run a public web site on someone else's Windows server...I don't recommend this at all, of course.

Comment: Since SFTP isn't part of the protocols supported by default under Windows, what limitation you place on it depends on the product you're using. Now, I am most positive that it's possible to allow SFTP without granting shell access (I know because I've written SFTP servers implementations for Windows applications AND I know of of at least one commercial SFTP server that explicitly let you configure that). Setting up WebDAV on the server isn't that much complex either but it is far less secure by default than SFTP.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I don't recommend running Windows at all. Which is why this question isn't about **my** servers.

Comment: I would add that anyone who isn't able to setup WebDAV properly on a windows server following one of the online walkthrough probably doesn't have any business running their own web server, and a Windows one even less so.

Comment: @Stephane if you know of a simple way (or product) for a novice to add SFTP access on Windows servers without requiring shell access, then by all means post it as an answer. That's what we're here for, after all.

Comment: This is against the rule of this web site but check out Bitvide SSH server: you have settings for enabling/disabling shell acces per user/group/globally.

Comment: @Stephane FWIW, there is no rule against linking to projects or software as part of your answer unless you work for the organization responsible for creating it. In which case, you can *still* link to the project, you just have to disclose your relationship ([and not be spammy about it](http://serverfault.com/faq#promotion)).

Comment: If you're doing read-only sharing, plain ol' http would do the trick honestly. For read/write, a public skydrive? Leave the hard stuff to people who know how to secure their stuff.

Comment: So supposedly these "people" have something worth securing but won't pay to have things done right? In this case WEBDAV is the solution, anything else they'll screw up and think they are secure when they truely are not.

Comment: One thing to note FTPS and SFTP are two different things.  I have two FTPS servers (IIS 7.5) set up with a SSL and leverage Filezilla for secure transfers.  It's easy to setup and administer.  Not sure what the hesitancy is about.  It's quick, simple, and does the job.

Answer (score 4):

I think the key problem highlighted by your no-go list is not file transfer, but the quality of the training the relevant adminitrators are given (or expected to have to start with). If an organisation can not setup something like this either in-house or through an outsourced IT infrastructure then I would be rather concerned as either a customer or an investor <sup><sub>(that comes over more aggressive/arrogant than I intended, but I can't think of a better way to word it...)</sub></sup>.

To address your points more directly:

> Cygwin + SSH

This can definitely be faf to setup with Cygwin, but there are commercial options that might be much easier to manage. SCP/SFTP (via SSH) does *not* necessarily imply shell access - in all implementations I'm aware of this can be removed from users or isn't possible in the first place. Under Linux restricted shells such as `rssh` are usually available, just set all your users to have one of them as their shell, so it is likely they exist in Cygwin's collection of ports too (or could be compiled locally if not). Another option if you are not convinced a restricted shell will be enough is to have the SSH loginc all go through a gateway box that contains absolutely nothing useful the users could run, and have it mount the other storage areas over the local network under the users' homes (though this would be even more hassle to setup).

> RDP, which while it has file-sharing capability, also grants the visitor desktop access, allowing him to do more than just upload and download files

I would agree that RDP/RDS is the wrong solution just for file sharing, though you can lock your RDP users down securely with very limited privileges.

> FTPS, FTPES, and other FTP-based solutions. Encryption isn't the only problem with FTP.

Agreed.

> Windows File Sharing, which is not safe for use over the Internet, and is typically blocked by ISPs for that reason

If you control the clients OSs that are connecting and they always connect over decent quality links then Windows File Sharing could be considered if only accessed via some form of VPN solution. Though if you see managing SSH as a major infrastructure management issue then the thought of a VPN could also be scary.

> DAV, unless it can be VERY easily set up and secured (which is typically not the case)

I've not worked with DAV myself, so can't comment with any authority here.

Comment: I don't think you're wrong, but you end up with a lot of conversations that sound like this: **Them**: The ___ keeps ___ing. **You**: Then stop using FTP. **Them**: What do I do instead? **You**: Well... have you considered a job in the food industry? --- I'd like to be able to help a bit more than that.

Comment: You can put a slightly more positive spin on it replace "have you considered a more menial job" with "I suggest you ready book X and attend course Y" or "how about outsourcing this" (though I'm generally very wary of the latter) - but essentially that is the situation IMO.

Comment: It could just be a confidence issue: they know what needs to be done but are worried they are going to miss something trying to secure the solution: in that case suggest they try it and have the result professionally penetration tested or otherwise reviewed by a security expert. All our systems/services are tested pen tested by an external party annually or before any major addition/change rolls out. This sometimes isn't cheap, but the assurance is nice (and *absolutely required* in some of the industries our clients operate in).